# CSV insert to database

Tags: codeigniter

This is not working as we discussed previously, for some reason and I have done is create some `$vars` for the uploaded file.

[Code available here (Pastebin).](http://pastebin.com/hY6CKVk6)

But never actually inserts anything

- When doing a `var_dump($csv_row)` i get: `bool(false)`
- `var_dump($fh)` shows: `resource(89) of type (stream)`
- `var_dump($insert_str)` shows all 1700 records from the csv file (obviously too big to post on here)

So I’m guessing the `while` statement or the whole from `if` statement is wrong somewhere. Really really would appreciate some help on this, I need to get it working by tomorrow (monday)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the codeigniter database library wrong. I can see a

```
$this->db->set($insert_str);
```

but no `$this->db->insert()` to be found. The `set()` method only useful with an `update()` or `insert()` following it, [See the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), search for `$this->db->set()`.

You either want to use the `$this->db->insert_batch()` (on the same doc page, unfortunately no direct links for sections) form and build up an array of arrays with your records (so you won't have to create a long sql string either).
Or you can use the `$this->db->query()` and just feed the `$insert_str` to it where you now call `$this->db->set()`.

---

According to your question:

> var_dump($insert_str) shows all 1700 records from the csv file

So i would rule out the possibility of the `while` loop or the `if` not working.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the top of the controller or before reading csv file

`ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`

Check if this will work for you